# form Validation with preventDefault() Bootstrap + React

Tags: reactjs, validation, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am currently working on an React app where I also use Bootstrap(Reactstrap).
Now I have a login form where I marked username and password as required, so there is a simple form validation.
But since it is react, I must use `preventDefault()`, because I want to make a custom post request and state management. This creates a problem, because with `preventDefault()` the validation from Bootstrap is not working anymore.

Can anyone help me or correct me if I do have a mistake here?

```
<form onSubmit={this.login}>
    <div id="login_form" className="min-vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" required onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} className="input-primary" /><br />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" required onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} className="input-primary" /><br />
        <button class="btn" type="submit" onClick={this.login} className="bg-color-primary button-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
-----------
login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        ...
        ...
}
```

Comment: No sure... your browser required validations should have kicked in.. this usually happens before submit is called.

Comment: it does not. if I use preventDefault(), which I have to do to be able to set a custom state and prevent reloading to show a new component/ page based on a post request, the validation is missing. or how should I improve/change up the login function/sequence/setup?